# If the derivative of a function is smaller than that of the other function, then?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a question regarding the derivative of two functions.
I am wondering if the following statement is true: If the derivative of a function (say, $f_1$) is smaller than that of the other function (say, $f_2$), then $f_1$ < $f_2$.

Mathematically speaking,

If $\frac{d}{dx} f_1(x) < \frac{d}{dx} f_2(x)$ for all $x$, then is it true that $f_1 < f_2$ for all $x$?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: consider the example $f_1(x)=10; f_2(x)=x$

Comment: did you mean also $f_1(x_0)=f_2(x_0)$ so $f_1<f_2$ for all $x>x_0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Take $$ f_1(x) = e^{-x}, \quad f_2(x) = 0.  $$
Then $$f_1'(x) = -e^{-x} < 0 = f_2'(x) $$
while $$ f_1(x) = e^{-x} > 0 = f_2(x). $$

Answer (score 0):

No. You can disprove this with
$$f_1(x)=x$$
$$f_2(x)=2x$$
for which $x\gt2x$ whenever $x\lt0$.